# XPath вытащить инфу, имея onclick="$('#1block').slideToggle('slow');"

Tags: парсер, xpath, web-scraping

Подскажите как добраться до данных "1Инфа", "2Инфа", "3Инфа" по отдельности:

```
 <div class="open" onclick="$('#1block').slideToggle('slow');" href="javascript://">    
     <h2 class="">1Инфа</h2>
</div>

<div class="open" onclick="$('#2block').slideToggle('slow');" href="javascript://"> 
     <h2 class="">2Инфа</h2>
</div>

<div class="open" onclick="$('#3block').slideToggle('slow');" href="javascript://"> 
     <h2 class="">3Инфа</h2>
</div>
```

`//div[@class='open']/h2`  так находит все данные

`//div[@click='$('#1block').slideToggle('slow');']/h2` не работает

`//div[contains(@onclick,'1block')]//h2` находит все данные

Answer (score 3):

Можно вот так и указывать нужный номер

```
//div[@class='open' and contains(@onclick,'1block')]/h2/text()
```